# Rethinkdb : i need a simple query in java to update the list of items

Tags: java, rethinkdb

This is my rethink document I need a simple query in java to update the menuItemIds list.

```
{
    "id":  "1a89a4b6-36a3-4378-8ddb-26d0d90f3055" ,
    "menuItemIds": [
        "178de705-59d7-4c5d-8a25-f7e0a226e510" ,
        "sfefe-edwef-wefwefwe-wef"
    ],
    "vendorId":  "e2c1e97d-3996-40c2-9c14-86f824203812"
}
```

Comment: initially i created the table by follownig code 
`Menu menu = new Menu();
            menu.setVendorId(menuItem.getVendorId());
            List<String> menuItemIDs = new LinkedList<>();
            menuItemIDs.add(menuId);
            menuItemIDs.add("sfefe-edwef-wefwefwe-wef");
            menu.setMenuItemIds(menuItemIDs);
            r.table("menu").insert(menu).run(conn);
            return new Response("OK","OK");`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, edit your question for adding aditional information about your problem. Keep the style on it and not post code like a comment. Hard to read...

Answer (score 0):

Updating a record in rethink works like this: fetch the row you want through get(id) and call update(). Pass the new list through a hashmap.

```
r.table('tableName').get("1a89a4b6-36a3-4378-8ddb-26d0d90f3055")
.update(r.hashMap("menuItemIds", newMenuList)).run(conn)
```

You might want to check out the [documentation](https://rethinkdb.com/api/java/update/).

Comment: yes , you are right but i need to update the nested array ??? which is "menuItemIds"

Comment: Does the record not update if you pass a new list of menuItemIds?